# How to parse a zonedDateTime string using React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a date coming as a extended format based on standard 8601 string from my backend (date + time + time zone + offset):

```
"2023-04-07T08:58:08+02:00[Europe/Paris]"
```

I want to parse it using:

```
import {parseZonedDateTime} from '@internationalized/date';

{parseZonedDateTime(myObject.date, 'compatible')}
```

api doc :

```
/**
 * Parses an ISO 8601 date and time string with a time zone extension and optional UTC offset
 * (e.g. "2021-11-07T00:45[America/Los_Angeles]" or "2021-11-07T00:45-07:00[America/Los_Angeles]").
 * Ambiguous times due to daylight saving time transitions are resolved according to the `disambiguation`
 * parameter.
 */
export function parseZonedDateTime(value: string, disambiguation?: Disambiguation): ZonedDateTime;
```

But what I get is:

"Invalid ISO 8601 date time string:"

Comment: Can someone pls explain how this question doesnt "meet SO guidelines" ?

Comment: remove `[Europe/Paris]` from `"2023-04-07T08:58:08+02:00[Europe/Paris]"`. Did you look up what a [valid 8601 format](https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime) is?

Comment: Do u understand 'Parses an ISO 8601 date and time string with a time zone extension and optional UTC offset (e.g. "2021-11-07T00:45[America/Los_Angeles]" or "2021-11-07T00:45-07:00[America/Los_Angeles]").' in an other way that I do ?

Comment: I'm using an extended format here, supposed to be covered by the lib I'm using.

Comment: The optional UTC offset is `+02:00` `[Europe/Paris]` is not ISO 8601. If your using an "extended format", then that is not ISO.

Comment: It is, just like the doc says "an ISO 8601 date and time string with a time zone extension and optional UTC offset", so I expected it to be parsable using the method "parseZonedDateTime", the question is : why it doesnt work ? why I get an error message about the "strict" ISO 8601 when the method is supposed to be able to parse an extended format ?

Comment: The UTC offset is `+02:00`. That says the timezone of this time is +2 hours from UTC. The bit on the end, i.e. `[Europe/Paris]`, is not valid ISO. So the parser is complaining about it. Remove `[Europe/Paris]` from the end of the string and try it. It will work

Comment: You can try it yourself here http://jsfiddle.net/wq7tjec7/14/

Comment: But you are just ignoring my inputs here, to match what you are used to do. My inputs are : 1. my lib is supposed to accept the `[Europe/Paris]` as shown in its examples,the parser is NOT supposed to complain about this, pls just read the provided doc and example 2. my dates include this part, because my date times come from a java zonedDateDatime "toString()", I want to parse these dates "as-is" with no pre-transformation

Comment: Well you can't use the library your trying to use then. You'll need to write your own. `@internationalized/date` does not do what you want it to do. I'm not aware of any library that will support this format, as it's none standard. That's kinda the point of standards

Comment: yes it does, or it's supposed to at least, just read the documentation I provide.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not reproducible, this snippet just works as documented with no error, and the consistency between offset and time zone is checked :

```html
<script type="module">
import {parseZonedDateTime} from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@internationalized/date@3.2.0/+esm'

console.log(parseZonedDateTime("2023-04-07T08:58:08+02:00[Europe/Paris]", 'compatible'));
</script>
```

gives :

```
{
  "calendar": {
    "identifier": "gregory"
  },
  "era": "AD",
  "year": 2023,
  "month": 4,
  "day": 7,
  "timeZone": "Europe/Paris",
  "offset": 7200000,
  "hour": 8,
  "minute": 58,
  "second": 8,
  "millisecond": 0
}
```

while :

```html
<script type="module">
import {parseZonedDateTime} from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@internationalized/date@3.2.0/+esm'

console.log(parseZonedDateTime("2023-04-07T08:58:08+04:00[Europe/Paris]", 'compatible'));
</script>
```

outputs an error message :

```
{
  "message": "Error: Offset +04:00 is invalid for 2023-04-07T08:58:08 in Europe/Paris",
  "filename": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@internationalized/date@3.2.0/+esm",
  "lineno": 7,
  "colno": 13340
}
```

Comment: Hey, this so far, the best answer, but I think what you say does not correspond to the documentation though. I think u missed this example : 'or "2021-11-07T00:45-07:00[America/Los_Angeles]"' where you can clearly see they cumulate offset and time zone, and it's supposed to be parsable with "parseZonedDateTime"

Comment: This extended format provided by the backend is called "ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME" : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME

Comment: Actually, when I add the "+02:00" and try "Run code snippet", it still works, but I don't know what is the difference between your code example and mine...  :/

Comment: I think I'm missing some basic React syntax since I'm completely new to React and javascript. Maybe "myObject.date" is not resolved to the actual value ?

Comment: Maybe it's just not initialized when I use it, this would correspond to the "Invalid ISO 8601 date time string:" message with no string after "string:"

Answer (score -1):

You can use different library

Use [day.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dayjs), Pleases

There is a [documentation](https://day.js.org/docs/en/installation/installation) for it

```
import dayjs from "dayjs"

....

const dayObj = dayjs("[TIME STRING]")
const month = dayObj.month()
```

Comment: Show a working example with the extended format I'm using pls : "2023-04-07T08:58:08+02:00[Europe/Paris]"